# Using a datetime margin in a SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, mysqli, timestamp

Bit of a double barrel question here. I have a table with 4 columns:

```
id  |  userid  |  systemid  |  datetime
```

Every time someone logs in a record is added to this table. What I'm trying to achieve is a query that allows me to count the number of UNIQUE userid's that are logged where system `id = x` from between 1st of the current month until the current time.

I'm hovering with the current syntax but am not aware of the best way to only add to the count once for each userid:

```
$mysqli->query("select count(userid) as c from log_logins where datetime between '[1st of this month]' and curdate()");
$result = $mysqli->fetch_object()->c;
```

Also, for this to work does the datetime column have to be a unix timestamp? The datetime column is currently set as this value: `<?php date('d/m/Y H:i', time()); ?>`

Thanks for any help in advance!
Michael

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:sql-server]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT userid)`:

```
$mysqli->query('
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS c
  FROM   log_logins
  WHERE  systemid = x
     AND datetime BETWEEN \'[1st of this month]\' AND CURDATE()
');
```

As regards the format of the `datetime` column, it should be a MySQL [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) type (which is stored internally as a UNIX timestamp).

Comment: Worked brilliantly, I'd never come across DISTINCT before so thank you very much